# Simple and local software to annotate videos

Tags: linux, video, video-editing, desktop-client, annotation

I need a simple tool to **edit** and **annotate** a video, simply.

- Annotations should look like YouTube annotations (bubbles or similar). Subtitles are not enough.
- It has to be available for Linux.
- I would like something like [Popcorn Maker](https://popcorn.webmaker.org/) (from Mozilla), but it has to run locally. Actually, that's exactly what I want, except I don't want to send my video online.

I tried OpenShot, which is quite ok, but annotations are not possible yet.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I need the same on windows.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by annotations? just putting text boxes over the video? This is usally called a title.

of course [OpenShot can do that](https://www.openshot.org/user-guide/) just use two tracks and make the titel not fill the entire screen.

same with [kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/features/)

shotcut even has their own [video tutorial](https://shotcut.org/tutorials/) on how to do it

Comment: Yes, use OpenShot and add a *Title*. In current version 3.1 there are already some nice examples in the "Title Library" which can be freely adjusted to your needs.